# ReplaceAll() not working in mobile JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In my following code I am trying to show the table code in textarea when page loads. My code is properly working in desktop device but when I am trying this in mobile phone the code not showing in textarea. I tried removing replaceAll then it's working in mobile as well. I don't understand why it's happening please help!

**Code:**

```js
function myFunction() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myTable");       
           
            
         document.getElementById("showTableCode").value=elem.outerHTML.replaceAll("<tbody>", '').replaceAll("</tbody>", '').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2,}/g, '\n');
}
```

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
<center>
<table id="myTable">
<tr><th><b>Fruit</b></th><th><b>Veg</b></th></tr>
<tr><td>Apple</td><td>Tomato</td></tr>
<tr><td>Banana</td><td>Potato</td></tr>
<tr><td>Mango</td><td>Online</td></tr>
</table></center><br>
<textarea cols="30"  style="width: 100%;" id="showTableCode" rows="10">
</textarea>
```

Comment: refer this: 
 https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceAll
Are you using correct browser?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

As of August 2020 the replaceAll() method is supported by Firefox but not by Chrome. It will become available in Chrome 85.

I hope this helps

Comment: What mobile do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
 a = a.replace(/<tbody>/g,"");
```

I am assuming everything in `a`, then you can apply this and no need of using of `replaceAll()`

Refer to this for more details [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)